# What's the difference between collision resistance and preimage  resistance?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography

For hash function, what's the difference for collision protection and preimage protection?

Comment: What do you mean by "protection"?

Comment: Belongs on http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/what-is-pre-image-resistance-and-how-can-the-lack-thereof-be-exploited

Comment: Also, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/why-doesnt-preimage-resistance-imply-the-second-preimage-resistance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

> ***Properties***
>
> Most cryptographic hash functions are designed to take a string of any
>   length as input and produce a fixed-length hash value. A cryptographic
>   hash function must be able to withstand all known types of
>   cryptanalytic attack. As a minimum, it must have the following
>   properties:
>
> **Preimage resistance** Given a hash *h* it should be difficult to find any message *m* such that *h = hash(m)*. This concept is related to that of one-way
>   function. Functions that lack this property are vulnerable to preimage
>   attacks.
>
> **Second-preimage resistance** Given an input *m*<sub>1</sub> it should be difficult to find another input *m*<sub>2</sub> — where *m*<sub>1</sub> != *m*<sub>2</sub> — such that *hash*( *m*<sub>1</sub> ) = *hash*( *m*<sub>2</sub> ). This property is
>   sometimes referred to as weak collision resistance, and functions that
>   lack this property are vulnerable to second-preimage attacks.
>
> **Collision resistance** It should be difficult to find two different messages *m*<sub>1</sub> and *m*<sub>2</sub> such that
>   *hash*( *m*<sub>1</sub> ) = *hash*( *m*<sub>2</sub> ). Such a pair is called a cryptographic hash
>   collision. This property is sometimes referred to as strong collision
>   resistance. It requires a hash value at least twice as long as that
>   required for preimage-resistance, otherwise collisions may be found by
>   a birthday attack.

Comment: I'm failing to see the difference between `pre-image` and `second pre-image`.. .can you explain better?

Comment: @CodyBugstein in pre-image attack, you are only leaking the hash H to the attacker, whereas in the second-preimage attack you are giving away both message m and the result of H(m). In both cases, the attacker has to find message m prime which will produce the same hash.

Comment: @CodyBugstein I'd also note that this classification is extremely fine-grained and somewhat hypothetical. In an ideal world, a cryptographic function would be truly one-way insofar there is one input corresponding to one and only one output, but because no one's ever been able to compute all of them, we cannot know.